# How to get Cucumber scenario steps details in java

Tags: cucumber, bdd

I'm using cucumber-jvm in my QA automation framework, in this framework once the scenario gets executed i pass on the scenario results to test case management tool testrail to update the pass/fail status.
To get the scenario details i use Scenario object and methods to retrive the neccessary details e.g scenario.getStatus(), scenario.getName(), etc

But is there a way/method which can give the details of scenario outline e.g. how many test scenario outlines and their individual test status?

Answer (score 0):

You can use either [built-in plugins](https://cucumber.io/docs/reference#reports) or 3rd party plugins (for example [cucumber-reporting](https://github.com/damianszczepanik/cucumber-reporting)).

Other options is use your CI, build-tool or test-runner reports(depending on your environment)